# Finding a special sequence of numbers (coordinates) in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, coordinates, python-re

We have two kind of coordinates in our project.
The normal one with x, y and z

Example:

```
101, 520, 62
960.93 764.22 59.20
```

And the extended version with 6 digits (2x xyz for position and rotation)
Example:

```
101 520 62 3 0 0
960.93 764.22 59.20 -0.34 0.00 -89.81
```

They can be negative, they can be floats and can be rounded numbers.
They can be separated by comma or by nothing

Using python, I am trying to find any coordinates in a string.

Example:

```
textbefore 101, 520, 62
GOTO 960.93 796.22 59.20 -0.34 0.00 -89.81
$5GOTO 1960.93 1796.22 159.20 -0.34 0.00 -89.81
501, 513, 162
1040, 1040, 520 text after 
error
222, 222
1500, 1500, 60  (1)
1337 1337 65
124.5, 133.6, 35.4
15:13:26  Condition: index_ != StringList::npos [line 178](125, 157, 215) 
Allocating shadow map cache 6324 x 6324: 76.28 MB
```

In the perfect world the output should be:

```
101 520 62
960.93 796.22 59.20 -0.34 0.00 -89.81
1960.93 1796.22 159.20 -0.34 0.00 -89.81
501 513 162
1040 1040 520
1500 1500 60
1337 1337 65
124.5 133.6 35.4
125 157 215
```

The last line with "Allocating shadow maps, is a bit tricky and if this fails and gets listed as coordinate, its fine.

I used this code here, which filters the numbers very good, then I was checking for 6 or 3 numbers, but I have problems with lines which have more numbers.
So I need somehow a logic which checks if there numbers are "close" to each other or even separated by words.

```
re.findall("[-+]?[.]?[\d]+(?:,\d\d\d)*[\.]?\d*(?:[eE][-+]?\d+)?", line)
```

If possible the code should work on Python 2.7 (Sadly we are far behind).

Thanks

Comment: Why not split your whole text by space, and then delete all commas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below regex for this

```
(?:(?:[+-]?\d+\.?\d*[ ,]+){5}[+-]?\d+\.?\d*)|(?:(?:[+-]?\d+\.?\d*[ ,]+){2}[+-]?\d+\.?\d*)
```

This will search for 2/5 consecutive numbers with `,` or `space` delimited and a 3rd/6th number with a non-digit value.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/CCOlz6/1) is a demo.

**Output**

```py
['101, 520, 62',
 '960.93 796.22 59.20 -0.34 0.00 -89.81',
 '1960.93 1796.22 159.20 -0.34 0.00 -89.81',
 '501, 513, 162',
 '1040, 1040, 520',
 '1500, 1500, 60',
 '1337 1337 65',
 '124.5, 133.6, 35.4',
 '125, 157, 215']
```

Comment: Awesome this worked, thank you. Also I didn't know about the regex expression editor, that's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting too far into the code, you need to figure out an algorithm or method in psuedocode which will do what you ask.
In this example you need to create python code to identify a number:

```
def is_number(input):
    if type(input) == int or type(input) == float:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then I would split on spaces or commas and parse through the array you create looking for 3 or 6 Trues in a row

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = '''textbefore 101, 520, 62
GOTO 960.93 796.22 59.20 -0.34 0.00 -89.81
$5GOTO 1960.93 1796.22 159.20 -0.34 0.00 -89.81
501, 513, 162
1040, 1040, 520 text after 
error
222, 222
1500, 1500, 60  (1)
1337 1337 65
124.5, 133.6, 35.4
15:13:26  Condition: index_ != StringList::npos [line 178](125, 157, 215) 
Allocating shadow map cache 6324 x 6324: 76.28 MB'''
s = s.split('\n')
s_row = []
for i in range(len(s)):
    s_row.append(s[i].replace(',', '').split(' '))

coord = []
for i in range(len(s_row)):
    coord_row = []
    for j in range(len(s_row[i])):
        try:
            s_row[i][j] = float(s_row[i][j])
            coord_row.append(s_row[i][j])
        except ValueError:
            None
    if coord_row != []:
        coord.append(coord_row)
```

will give you following output:

```
[[101.0, 520.0, 62.0]
[960.93, 796.22, 59.2, -0.34, 0.0, -89.81]
[1960.93, 1796.22, 159.2, -0.34, 0.0, -89.81]
[501.0, 513.0, 162.0]
[1040.0, 1040.0, 520.0]
[222.0, 222.0]
[1500.0, 1500.0, 60.0]
[1337.0, 1337.0, 65.0]
[124.5, 133.6, 35.4]
[157.0]
[6324.0, 76.28]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a regular expression. Since the `re` module that ships with python doesn't handle repeating or nested capture groups well, you are best off assembling a larger regex from parts.

```
r"([-+]?[\d+][\.\d]*)"
```

is a regular expression that will match a decimal or float with optional sign. `[-+]?` matches the sign, `[\d+]` matches at least 1 decimal before a dot, `[\.\d]*` matches the optional fractional part of the float and the outer `()` tells the regex to emit the captured string.

```
r"[ ,]*"
```

is the separator between the decimal/floats. Now you could just write out 3 and 6 of these things together, but the code below does that with a bit of python.

```
import re
import io

test = io.StringIO("""textbefore 101, 520, 62
GOTO 960.93 796.22 59.20 -0.34 0.00 -89.81
$5GOTO 1960.93 1796.22 159.20 -0.34 0.00 -89.81
501, 513, 162
1040, 1040, 520 text after 
error
222, 222
1500, 1500, 60  (1)
1337 1337 65
124.5, 133.6, 35.4
15:13:26  Condition: index_ != StringList::npos [line 178](125, 157, 215) 
Allocating shadow map cache 6324 x 6324: 76.28 MB""")


# assemble regex from matching 1 decimal or float coord into 3 or 6
_one = r"([-+]?[\d+][\.\d]*)"
_sep = "[ ,]+"
coord_3 = re.compile(_sep.join([_one]*3))
coord_6 = re.compile(_sep.join([_one]*6))

coords = []
for line in test:
    match = coord_6.search(line) or coord_3.search(line)
    if match is not None:
        print(match.groups())
        coords.append(" ".join(match.groups()))

for c in coords:
    print(c)
```

Comment: I tried to use r"([-+]?[\d+][\.\d]*)" to parse a string contains three float like, "-1.23 2.0 1", only -1.23 can be parsed. Does that mean [-+]? requried one '-' or '+' at least? how to adapt float with and without sign？@tdelaney